# Get windows, move and resize on Windows

Tags: python, windows, window, xlib

I'm on Windows and I need to get one window by title name then move and resize it. The code below is for unix only because fcntl doesn't exist on Windows.

```
import Xlib
import Xlib.display

display = Xlib.display.Display()
screen = display.screen()
root = screen.root
tree = root.query_tree()
wins = tree.children

for win in wins:
    print (win.get_wm_name())
    win.configure(x=123, y=345, width=678, height=910)
    win.change_attributes(win_gravity=X.NorthWestGravity, bit_gravity=X.StaticGravity)
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'

Do you have an alternative to this please ? Then how to get the windows which has the title "Hello there" ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this and it is working :

```
import win32gui, win32con

win2find = 'Skype'
whnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(None, None, None, win2find)
if not (whnd == 0):
    print('Skype')
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(whnd, win32con.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 500, 600, 0)
```